# How a trigger on a table works on insert event?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, triggers

Hypothetically, I am going to develop a trigger that inserts a record to Table A when an insertion made to an Table A.

Therefore, I want to know how the system handles that kind of loophole or it is going to continue as a loop until the system hangs which requires restart and possibly remove the DB.

I'm trying to gather information on almost every DBMS on this issue or loophole.

Comment: So... mysql or oracle? Can't be both.

Comment: I used both tags to attract more people to see this. I'm sorry if I confuse you or cause you any kind of touble. @Aquillo

Comment: The problem here is that you're referencing two different DBMS, which may respond in different ways. In order for people to help you, it can be important to know with which DBMS you're working.

Comment: Ah, actually it's random. I do not have a specific DBMS to search for. I'm trying to gather information on any DB. If you are an expert any of them, You are welcome to comment. I'm just trying to find DB security..>!

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak to Oracle, I know nothing of MySQL.

In Oracle, this situation is known as mutation.  Oracle will not spiral into an endless loop.  It will detect the condition, and raise an ORA-04091 error.

That is:

```
ORA-04091: table XXXX is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

The standard solution is to define a package with three functions and a package level array. The three functions are as follows:

1. initialize - this will only zero out the array.
2. save_row - this will save the id of the current row (uk or pk) into the arrray.
3. process_rows - this will go through the array, and actually do the trigger action for each row.

Now, define some trigger actions:

statement level BEFORE: call initialize
row level BEFORE or AFTER:  call save_row
statement level AFTER:  call process_rows

In this way, Oracle can avoid mutation, and your trigger will work.

More details and some sample code can be found here:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936

Comment: Hi Mark. A technical style of writing is preferred on Stack Overflow. Given that no authors post an answer hoping it doesn't help, the phrase "hope it helps" is rather redundant. I have sometimes wondered if subconsciously a form of vote pleading. Anyway, editors will tend to remove these, and we don't have enough editors to handle the workload. If you could have mercy on those volunteers, and stick to brevity, they would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can only insert a record in same table if you are using instead of trigger. In all other cases you can only modify the record being inserted.

I hope this answers your quest.

Comment: I kinda get that, but that's not the answer I was looking for! If this trigger was executed for For Insert, what would happen?

Comment: @gayan1991 if you are writing a trigger "For Insert" you can only insert a record in same table. This insertion won't fire the trigger again. It's basic rule current version of standard databases follows.

Comment: Could it depend on DBMS ? I think, especially in old DBMS, this mutation problem was not handled such as Microsoft Windows Server 2005. Therefore, I would like to know in which provide this solution and have you tried this? Oracle DBMS stops this kind of troublesome stuff at trigger creation.

Comment: Agree, old version of DBMS systems had mutation issues which was then rectified in later version.

Answer (score 0):

you can create trigger in mysql DBMS.
check below link for create insert trigger syntex

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php

Comment: Alright!!!. Let's say, hypothetically, you create a trigger for Table A to insert record to Table A and you are triggering this whenever an Insert is made. Then you insert a record to Table A. Could you tell me what happen next?

Comment: after insert record in table A then same value again insert in table A.

Comment: First Insertion is made by user. Second Insertion is by Trigger. When the second record is made, isn't the trigger going to be executed again?

Comment: Trigger may fall into an infinite loop when you use INSERT in an action of a trigger where an INSERT event is defined.

Comment: Ah yeah. May I know what DB you are expert in? and Have you tried or fallen into any situation like this?